# disable writing to a page of memory, per thread on linux on x86_64

Tags: gcc, openmp, stack-overflow

Is there a way a process can mark one of its memory pages as unwriteable for a specific set of threads on Linux?

**Background**

I'm attempting to debug a tricky pointer problem in an OpenMP-enhanced C++ application.  The behavior I observe is that the program segfaults after a random amount of time.  Given a binary, it always segfaults in the same place, but if I change the binary (by commenting out code or changing compilation options), the line of code that causes the segfault changes.  The work done in each OpenMP thread is trivial.

If I use gdb to inspect the stack on the segfaulting thread, I observe a single pointer that has been corrupted to point to a near-NULL address.  The pointer variable resides on the stack and points to a heap address.  I'd like to have each OpenMP thread mark its stack as unwriteable for all other threads to ensure there are no stack overflow problems or other cases of one thread walking on another's stack.

Setting `OMP_STACKSIZE` to a large value (say 10M) makes the problem go away, but I suspect this is just luck.  As best I can tell, I'm using << 100K of stack space for any thread.

valgrind's memcheck reports no problems.

All memory allocations are performed in single-threaded code in the main thread.  If any race conditions are handled improperly, they would result in incorrect output, but should not result in pointer problems.

**EDIT:** Eventually, I found my bug.  I was using a `const` instance of a class that has a `mutable` `private` member, for some lazy evaluation.  There was a race condition arising from that `mutable` member.  The solution was to trigger an eager evaluation before entering the parallel block.  As to the title question, I suspect that @Damon's comment is correct.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I'm 99% inclined to say: No! The reason being that page access goes by address space, and threads share one address space. So it's all threads, or none. But you could probably do this indirectly, by making pages unwritable for the process (this is obviously trivial) and installing a `SIGSEGV` handler that resets the page to being writeable depending on what thread caused the fault (and maybe logs some info, too). Only problem would be how to reset it again, in a non-race way.

Comment: Use a thread checker tool like the one that comes with Oracle Solaris Studio (despite the name there is a Linux version and it's free) or with Intel tools.